# Textarea hold more than one affected value

Tags: css, angular

I have a textarea field where i want to view the content of an object of objects but it's only accept one affected value

This is my object :

```
{
  name: 'Will',
  test: 'test',
  type: ['variable', 'result'],
}
```

and this is my textarea in my css file :

```
<mat-form-field class="description" *ngFor="let d of description">
  <textarea
    [(value)]="d.name"
    matInput
    cdkTextareaAutosize
    cdkAutosizeMinRows="2"
    cdkAutosizeMaxRows="4"></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

How can i view all the objects inside my object inside the same textarea field

Comment: [(value)]="d" ?

Comment: @Jazib i get [object Object], i need to specify

Comment: can you tell me what the expected output should be ?

Comment: @Jazib the expected  output is to show all the objects inside my description object in the textarea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<mat-form-field class="description" *ngFor="let d of description">
  <textarea
    matInput
    cdkTextareaAutosize
    cdkAutosizeMinRows="2"
    cdkAutosizeMaxRows="4">{{ d | json }}</textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

will work. I strongly advise to NOT bind your textarea to anything and not let any user modify your object.

Note that since it relies on `JSON.stringify`, you won't be able to convert circular structures, so be careful with that solution of yours.

Comment: But why i couldn't let the user modify my object

Comment: @brxnzaz this is a serious security concern, it can seriously impact your application, or even your API in some cases. Don't let your user directly touch the JS structure, unless that user knows what he is doing ! instead, offer him to edit every field separately.

Comment: but is it normal to cause this problem ==> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'mat-form-field-should-float: false'. Current value: 'mat-form-field-should-float: true'.

Comment: This comes from something you are doing in `ngAfterViewInit` probably. But this has nothing to do with the solution, it's a lifecycle issue that means you have set the value of a variable after the view has been checked.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a answer.

```
export class FormFieldOverviewExample implements OnInit {
  description = [
    {
      name: 'Will',
      test: 'test',
      type: ['variable', 'result'],
    }
  ]
  ngOnInit(){
    for(let i of this.description){
      (i as any).string = JSON.stringify(i);
    }
  }
}

<mat-form-field class="description" *ngFor="let d of description">
<textarea
  [value]="d.string"
  matInput
  cdkTextareaAutosize
  cdkAutosizeMinRows="2"
  cdkAutosizeMaxRows="4"></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

you can use    `[innerHtml]` like this:

```
<mat-form-field class="description" *ngFor="let d of description">
      <textarea
      [innerHtml]="d.name + ' ' + d.test "
        matInput
        cdkTextareaAutosize
        cdkAutosizeMinRows="2"
        cdkAutosizeMaxRows="4"></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Have a look at this stackbliz_link i have created :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-form-field-31d3vp?file=app%2Fform-field-prefix-suffix-example.html

Comment: What if the object has 77 properties ? Will you write them all ?

Comment: With due respect ,I think that is not the case here . And even if that is the case then i would suggest to create description a list of strings rather than doing {{ d | json }} because no user wants to see curly braces on their screen as it is bad user experience.

Comment: If we are litteral and stick to that use case, `I have a textarea field where i want to view the content of an object of objects but it's only accept one affected value` => meaning that on the spot, your solution doesn't work, since it will display `[object Object] [object Object]`. And to answer you, I agree it's not great to show braces, but it seems to be what the OP expected. All of this to say that your solution have a major drawback, which is reusability.

Comment: To make it reusable we can do like this : [innerHtml]="fun(d)"  and return whatever needed but I am not sure what is the priority here : user experience or reusability . We should do what is needed according to scnerio...

Comment: *We* shouldn't do anything but answer the question. No need to make assumptions, the OP will do his work, we don't have to do it for him :) Anyway, that was just my two cents on your answer !